# obtener la ruta de una imagen mostrada en un imageview swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, swift4

Hola trato de hacer un formulario de registro con una foto tomada desde la libreria y mostrada a un imagenview, solo me funciona si tengo la imagen en el proyecto mas no desde la galeria. ayuda por favor esto iniciando con xcode.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class RegistroController: 
UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

}

@IBAction func cargarimagen(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func registrar(_ sender: Any) {


    let parameters = ["nombre":nombrer, "apellidos":apellidosr, "zona":zonar, "area":cargosr,"email":emailr,"password":passwordr,"codempleado":codr]
    let imageToUploadURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "30601611", withExtension: "jpeg")
    let url = "http://localhost/prueba/registro.php"

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageToUploadURL!, withName: "imagen")
            for (key, val) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(val.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
    },
        to: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let jsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                        print(jsonResponse)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    }
    )
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : 
 Any]) {
if let pickedImage = 
 info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        imagen.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imagen.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) 
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

como pueden ver mi codigo, el hae el registro de la informacion en el servidor y sube la imagen pero el problema es que necesito subir la imagen selecionada o mostrada el en imagenview.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si tu codigo sube una imagen al servidor de donde obtienes esa imagen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trata con este codigo dentro de tu `IBAction` `cargarimagen`

```
@IBAction func cargarimagen(_ sender: Any) {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
    print("No se pudo acceder a la libreria de fotos")
  }
}
```